# Decrease crypted LVM partition

Tags: lvm, encryption, gparted

On a Linux Mint install, I used the option to use whole disk and encrypt it.
Now, I want to install Windows on another partition.
How I can safely decrease size of this encrypted LVM? Of course, partitions created by installer.

Comment: I guess you are not going to reduce just a LV but you have to reduce the whole PV in order to make space for a Windows partition. Encryption does not really change the process. The main question is: How to reduce an LV and its PV afterwards? This has probably already been answered here. You should search for such answers and change the title of your question.

Comment: The procedure is not "trivial" and not even easy, but there is a howto on the AskUbuntu community that can be of great help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/262211/how-do-i-resize-an-encrypted-lvm-to-install-another-copy-of-ubuntu .You will probably need a livecd media and follow strictly the steps. A backup is essential.